# Printing a label in asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I'm trying to print the info entered by a user using a label in VB. I used the label's ID to do so but surprisingly it gives an error I don't really know why, I made sure the label's ID is correct and it actually is..what could be the problem? (I'm new to VB and learning)

```
Protected Sub submitbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitbutton.Click
    welcomelabel.Text = "~!Welcome back " & namebox.Text & ", " & genderlist.Text & ", from " & citylist.Text & ".Thank you for your comment : " & commentbox.Text & "."

End Sub
```

Comment: @OneFineDay the error is in the " welcomelabel.Text" it says " welcomelabel" is not declared

Comment: then you don't have the name correct. Recheck it.

Comment: @OneFineDay The name is corret, I checked that

Answer (score 0):

You must use `runat="server"` to see it in code behind.

```
<asp:label ID="welcomelabel" runat="server".../>
```

Comment: where should I add that line ?

Comment: I think it has to do with the accessibility of "welcomelabel" because the error says it's protected